# Multiple counts for certain values in same column with group by

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have an event table that run different accounts. We I need to count certain types of events by account.

Input:

```
| accountId | eventType |
|-----------|-----------|
| 1         | start     |
| 1         | stop      |
| 1         | start     |
| 1         | start     |
| 2         | start     |
| 2         | start     |
```

Query:

`select accountId, count(eventType='start') as starts, count(eventType='stop') as stops FROM eventTable GROUP BY accountId`

Expected output:

```
| accountId | starts    | stops     |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 1         | 3         | 1         |
| 2         | 2         | 0         |
```

It seems it just tries to assign a value and counts the same for all values - which is not intended. There would be a work around using

`sum(case when eventType='start' then 1 alse 0) as starts`

but is there a better (cleaner) way using the counts direcly?

Edit:
I'm using Athena, so HIVE/Presto Syntax and behaviour is preferred.

Comment: Sorry, first post - edit window stated Markdown is supported. Shoudl mabe repohrase to 'partially supported'. Will reformat tables.

Comment: `count(case when eventType='start' then 1 end)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing a `from` clause but I assume this is a typo.

Consider:

```
select 
    accountId, 
    sum(eventType = 'start') as starts, 
    sum(eventType = 'stop') as stops 
from ???
GROUP BY accountId
```

Rationale: `count()` takes in account all values that are not `null`. On the other hand, as long as |`eventType` is not `null`, the condition inside the `count()` returns a boolean or a `0/1` valu - depending on your database. What you want is to `sum()` these `0/1` values.

Note that the above syntax is supported in MySQL only. If you are running Postgres (which is another database in which your original code would run), no need for this, you can use a `filer` clause instead:

```
select 
    accountId, 
    count(*) filter(where eventType = 'start') as starts, 
    count(*) filter(where eventType = 'stop') as stops 
from ???
GROUP BY accountId
```

Comment: Doesn't work as it's a VARCHAR value, not a number: 
`Unexpected parameters (boolean) for function sum. Expected: sum(double) , sum(real) , sum(bigint) , sum(decimal(p,s)) `

Comment: @DennisMeyer: which databasea are you using, is this Postgres?

Comment: Athena, so HIVE/Presto. Edited my question regardingly.

Comment: The filter statement works in Athena!

I guess it's also more performant than doing a transformation on the data using the case statement (although this might be more relevant on 'real' RDBMS like MySQL, Postgres etc as HIVE runs through the data anyway).

Comment: Accepted your answer, but will get public only after reputation has been reached ;-)

Comment: That's exactly what I did - as I mentioned. You'll just not see it until then.

Comment: @supernova: ok - I was not aware of this type of restriction on accept... For my understanding: what does the message say exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.